# jQuery user input on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, submit

I have a an HTML page with an input area and a submit button.

I am using jQuery to alert the user of what their input is. (Really I am trying to store that in a variable but that will be trivial once I get this working).

Can someone help me understand why it is not working, as well as a solution? Thanks.

The HTML form is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="grid_size">
            <button type="submit">Submit Me!</button>
        </form>
        <!-- Add jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The custom jQuery I am using is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
    alert( grabUserInput )});
});

function grabUserInput() {
    return $("form").find(".grid-size").val();
}
```

Comment: That text `input` needs a `label`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your class grid_size, and search for a class grid-size in javascript code.
This code should fix a typo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        alert( grabUserInput() );
    });
});

function grabUserInput() {
    return $("form").find(".grid_size").val();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I also forgot the parenthesis at the end of the grabUserFunction().

Answer (score 1):

Try this -- `grabUserInput` is a function, not a variable -- so you have to include `()` to invoke the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        alert( grabUserInput() );
    });
});
```

And your markup has to match your selector:

```
 <input type="text" class="grid-size">
```

**BONUS**:

In case all you want is to alert the value, and you do not want to submit the form use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        alert( grabUserInput() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try to put some id

```
<input id="input_grid_size" type="text" class="grid_size">
<button id="button_submit" type="submit">Submit Me!</button>
```

and jq

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button_submit").click(function() {
    alert($('#input_grid_size').val()); }); });
```

it seem your code also forgot the ";" and "()" in the alert